# AWS Lambda Invoke Using Serverless Can't Import handler.py

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dependencies, serverless

I deployed my serverless framework and my aws lambda function successfully. When I tried to invoke it using

```
serverless invoke --function lambdaExampleLavi --stage dev --region eu-central-1
```

I got an error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler': cannot import name 'ObjectIdentifier' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)",
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "requestId": "b31bdfc2-c9e3-48ee-bd0d-5e47aec3424a",
    "stackTrace": []
}
```

I tried to upgrade the cryptography package, but didn't help. Any idea?

I upgraded the cryptography package, checked all the dependencies and checked that problem all over the internet, without success.

Comment: Was the `cryptography` package uploaded in your Lambda function deployment package or otherwise available via a Lambda Layer? Can you successfully package, upload, and import other third-party packages? Also, troubleshooting guide [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python).

Comment: Hi,I checked and yes, it's uploaded, and other third-party packages had successfully uploaded

Comment: Related issue [here](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/9060). Suspect some package incompatibility or lack of some underlying native library.